# Open link in a pdf(already loaded into an Iframe) into another iframe

Tags: c#, pdf, iframe, itext

I have been given a task to load a pdf into an iframe. That pdf contains numerous links that points to another pdf. On clicking any link I have to show the destination in another pdf.That pdf should be loaded into second iframe. I am in the middle of nowhere in this situation and I am new in handling pdfs. Please suggest what should be done. I can modify the source pdf using itextsharp(if needed). I am using c#.

Comment: HTML can "embed" a PDF as long as there is a local renderer (Acrobat, etc.) available but there is no spec about HTML/JS "talking" to the PDF so that's out. PDF has "links" that are similar to HTML but they basically only have a URL so there's nothing there either. PDF does have JavaScript and that JavaScript can (in theory) "talk" to the host (browser/Acrobat/etc.) but there isn't a universal spec for that and many renderers don't even support it so that's probably out, too. If possible, I'd recommend making your first frame HTML instead of PDF so that you can achieve your goals.

Comment: @ChrisHaas: Got it. So I have to somehow read the pdf in order to convert it into html and then create links in the html to redirect it into the pdfs. However, will it be possible if the user has to create these links on the given UI i.e. link and destination in different panes(or iframe, or anything). Thanks in advance..